# Probability Question with Onto function / Using of Stirling Numbers to solve Qn

Tags: probability, functions, logic, combinations, stirling-numbers

How many onto functions are there from a set with four elements to a set with two elements?

I thought of this question in such a way:
Lets say set 1: {a,b,c,d}, set 2: {x,y}
Method: 4C2 * 2 * 2 = 24
Logic: Out of the four elements, I choose 2 of them. (This 2 will each be attached to x and y respectively). The other 2 elements left in set 1 can then select to go to x or y. (2 choices each).

However the answer to solution is:  $ \binom{4}{3}\binom{1}{1} + \binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2} + \binom{4}{1}\binom{3}{3}$ = 14

I get the solution's logic but can someone help me point out from my logic which cases did I double counted? Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you choose $a$ and $b$ to send to $x$ and $y$, and then $c$ and $d$ get sent there as well, that’s the same as if you chose $c$ and $d$ in the first place, and then $a$ and $b$ followed.

In this case, you could really write down all 24 of your list, and then just see which ones are redundant.

There are only $2^4=16$ total functions from $\{a,b,c,d\}\to\{x,y\}$, anyway, and only two of them fail to be onto. That’s probably the easiest way to count it.

Comment: Hey thanks man. But what if I want to use Stirling Numbers of the second kind? Will it then be S (4.2) * 2! ? // S(4.2) will be case of 4C3 or 4C2 to partition 4 elements into 2 subsets? Is my method of using Stirling Numbers wrong?

Comment: If you want to use Stirling numbers, then this is just $S(4,2)\cdot 2!$, as you said. In general, I think inclusion/exclusion is a good approach, which is particularly simple in this case: $2^4-\binom21 1^4$.